# Sorting own adapter by RatingBar doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, listview, sorting, ratingbar

My application contains ListView of all instaled apps (TextView and RatingBar) and allows sorting elements of ListView according to ranking (selected in the menu).
It means, after choosing option from menu sort->ranking->descending f.e., ListView which contains name of installed apps and ranking, should be sorted in descending order according to ranking. The problem is that the ListView isn't totally sorted. It works but without few elements, but.. after scrolling screen is ok. Could I get some clue?

I noticed, that when adapter is sorted , only visible items of ListView have correct ranking, others are equal to zero. Why is that?

Piece of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "myPreferences3";
    public SharedPreferences pref;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
    public ListView listView;
    public List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    public PackageManager pm;
    public App app_packages[];
    public AppAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pref=getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefEditor = pref.edit(); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        pm=getPackageManager();
        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        app_packages=new App[packages.size()];

        int i=0; 
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
        {
            app_packages[i]=new App(pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo).toString());
            i++;
        }

         adapter = new AppAdapter(this, R.layout.app, app_packages);
         listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
             listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
         }


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<App> 
    {
        private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "myPreferences3";
        public SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        public SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor=pref.edit();

       Context context; 
       App applications_array[]=null;
       int layoutResourceId;

       public AppAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, App[] applications_array)
       {
           super(context, layoutResourceId, applications_array);  
           this.layoutResourceId=layoutResourceId;
           this.context=context;
           this.applications_array=applications_array;
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
       {           
           View app=convertView;  
           AppHolder holder=null;

           if(app==null) 
           {
               LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();     
               app=inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

               holder=new AppHolder();
               holder.textView=(TextView)app.findViewById(R.id.appTitle);
               holder.ratingBar=(RatingBar)app.findViewById(R.id.appScore);
               app.setTag(holder);
           }
           else
           {
               holder=(AppHolder) app.getTag();
           }



        holder.ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
           public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                prefEditor.putFloat("rating"+applications_array[position].title, rating).commit();

                            applications_array[position].rating=rating;
                            switch(pref.getString("sort", ""))
                            { 
                                case "r_up": Sort_r_up(); 
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                                    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getPosition(applications_array[position]));
                                    break;
                                case "r_down": Sort_r_down();
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getPosition(applications_array[position]));
                                    break;
                            }
                } 
                }); 
                holder.textView.setText(applications_array[position].title);
                holder.ratingBar.setRating(pref.getFloat("rating"+applications_array[position].title, 0.0f));

            return app;
       } 
    }


    static class AppHolder
    { 
        TextView textView; 
        RatingBar ratingBar;
    }

    public class App
    {
        public String title;
        public float rating;


        public App(){}

        public App(String title)
        {
            this.title=title;
            this.rating=0.0f;
        }

    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {

                 case R.id.r_up:
                prefEditor.putString("sort", "r_up").commit();
            Sort_r_up(); 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            case R.id.r_down:
                prefEditor.putString("sort", "r_down").commit();
                Sort_r_down();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    public void Sort_r_up()
    {
         adapter.sort(new Comparator<App>()
         {
             public int compare(App arg0, App arg1) {
                    if(arg0.rating>arg1.rating)
                        return 1;
                    else 
                        return -1;
                }
         });
    }

    public void Sort_r_down() 
    {
         adapter.sort(new Comparator<App>()
         {  
             public int compare(App arg0, App arg1) {
                    if(arg0.rating>=arg1.rating)
                        return -1;
                    else 
                        return 1; 
             }    
         });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to call **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** method when you sort list item at runtime.

Comment: not quite see what should I improve. Would you be able to describe where exactly it's missing?